# Computing the mean and variance of the ratio of two Laplace variables

Tags: density-function, laplace-distribution

I know that Laplacian distribution function is defined as follow

$$ f(x)=\frac{b}{2}\exp(-b|x-\mu|) $$

Also, I know that the mean and variance for the ratio between two normal variables like $$c=\frac{a}{b}$$

Anyone can guide how would be mean and variance for Laplacian distribution?

Comment: How do you get those results for normal variables?

Comment: Thanks for attention. You can read it in "A Novel Gain Invariant Quantization-Based Watermarking Approach"

Comment: Found where they say something like it - you could have saved time by saying it was in the appendix. It doesn't state what you have above, and what it does actually say relies on the convergence of the Taylor series (... and therein lies a problem)

Comment: You have equalities in your question. 1. Taylor series don't give equalities. 2. For the approximation to work, Taylor series need all the later terms to be relatively small.

Comment: The integration can be carried out exactly to find the full distribution of the ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mean and variance are not actually finite in either the Gaussian nor the Laplace case.

You can try to use a Taylor expansion as they did in the paper you mention, but for that to actually be correct, you need the Taylor series to converge.

The problem arises because the denominator has non-zero density in the neighborhood of zero.

If you bound the denominator away from zero (whereupon you no longer have the ratio of two Laplaces or of two normals) then it may be that the Taylor approach will work, but even then it would be an approximation, not an exact formula.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. Should I just replace the Gaussian Mu by mu laplacian mu and Gaussian variance with 2b^2 to estimate the ratio? Am I right?

Comment: My answer explains why it won't work (and why the paper is wrong).

Comment: I found the pdf of the ration between two Laplacian distibutions which is f(x) = (1/2)(s2/s1)(1/(1+(s2/s1)*|x|))^2 for x member of R

Comment: I have got it from The Laplace Distribution and Generalizations page 51

Comment: Is it possible to find the ratio mean and the ratio variance based on this pdf?

Comment: I have already stated (in the very first sentence of my post) that the mean and the variance of the ratio -- for both Laplace and for Gaussian variables -- are not finite.  Is there something about that statement you don't quite understand?

Comment: sorry to bothering you :) I am very far from statistics.

Comment: Sure, but "not finite" isn't a statistical term, it's mathematical, and it's not something you can ignore and have it go away. I explained in my answer the conditions under which some progress could be made, but nothing can actually rescue the problem as stated. You may like to consider asking a new question that doesn't incur the same difficulty.

Comment: tnx so much for your wisdom

Comment: In respect of the book reference you mention in comments above, that's only for the case of 0-mean Laplace variates with the same variance, and they already give the mean and variance on p52 (though the statement that the mean is "infinite" there isn't quite correct; it's undefined)